# Guru mediation 403 error on using image preview link fetched from reddit

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, axios, reddit

So basically I've been trying to fetch the wallpaper links from reddit.com/r/wallpapers and use them in some images in a vue file using axios. 
However, when retrieving, the preview links `(postObjList[0].data.preview.images[0].source.url)` are giving me the above-mentioned error, even when I try to manually enter them on my chrome address bar. What is wrong and how to solve this?

```
<template>
      <div class="hello">
        <img id= "test" src="" alt="">
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>

    const axios = require('axios')
    export default {
      name: 'HelloWorld',
      props: {
        msg: String
      },
      created() {
        axios.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpapers.json')
        .then(response => {
          let postObjList = response.data.data.children
          console.log(postObjList)
          let thumbnail = postObjList[0].data.preview.images[0].source.url
          console.log(thumbnail)
          document.getElementById("test").src = thumbnail
        })
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Got an old reddit thread that already answered the same problem.
[reddit link](https://old.reddit.com/r/redditdev/comments/9ncg2r/changes_in_api_pictures/)

As to why `&amp;` is causing 403 error is unclear to me. However, [Why use &amp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084237/what-is-amp-used-for) provides useful information.

[Linking another post about similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39193800/403-error-when-trying-to-get-data-from-reddit-api?rq=1) for future reference.